# check the condition on the value, and store in a new field in MongoDB

Tags: arrays, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have 4 parameters, `param1 = All comparison operator >, < etc with dropdown list`. `param2 = AnyValueUserGiveAsInput`. `param3 All comparison operator >, < etc with dropdown list But its Optional`. `param4 = AnyValueUserGiveAsInput but optional`.
`param1 and param2 is mandatory`  now we need the data if the user selected from `param1 = Grater than >` , `param2 input 25`, `param3 = less than equal <=`  and `param4 input is 100`. Please check the output we will add one new field that will be the `fl` that stores the result `value` is true or false.

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "value": 100
        },
        {
            "value": 300
        },
        {
            "value": 14
        },
        {
            "value": 3
        },
        {
            "value": 30
        },
        {
            "value": 60
        }
    ]
}
```

Expected output : Check the condition > 25 and <= 100. all document and structure remain as it is and a new field `f` will add that store the results `0`, `1`

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "value": 100,
             "fl" :1

        },
        {
            "value": 300,
             "fl" :0
        },
        {
            "value": 14,
             "fl" :0
        },
        {
            "value": 3
             "fl" :0
        },
        {
            "value": 30,
             "fl" :1
        },
        {
            "value": 60,
             "fl" :1
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Is [this example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/P_yAXW47oMQ) what are you looking for? I can explain better in an answer.

Comment: but this is static,  right, how I can perform more dynamically. I want to pass the operator from the parameter. or check the condition base in `if`

Comment: You are using a programming language I guess, you can create the query according to the parameters. How do you get the parameters?

Comment: I am using just MongoDB

Comment: In a shell prompt?

Comment: i have to make an interface in a query for the user. no i am not using prompt

Comment: This question is very difficult to understand.

Comment: @barrypicker which part you understand please let me know

Comment: well, for starters, I don't understand `param1 = All comparison operator >, < etc with dropdown list.`

Comment: so in `param1` you have operators >. < , <=,  >= , == and != etc. user will select one of them